# Rails: link_to does not generate params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For `<%= link_to 'Date', posts_path, category: 'date' %>`, it will generate `current_path/posts?category=card`

But when I use a helper,

```
def tag_link(post, link_path)
  category = 'card'
  label_class = 'info'
  link_to(link_path, category: category) do
    content_tag(:span, :class => "label label-#{label_class}") do
      post.category
    end
  end
end
```

And use it in view like `<%= tag_link item, posts_path %>`. 
It only generates `http://localhost:3000/posts`, the `?category=` is skipped.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is there a restriction to not use RESTful routes? You're trying to create `http://localhost:3000/posts?category=category_name` why not `http://localhost:3000/category/category_name/posts`?

Comment: @User089247 Well...not. I just have not create a model for this(`Category`). Now I'm just quering an attribute to get the specific category.

Comment: You don't need to create a model `Category` just for query. You can create a route: `get 'category/:categroy_name/posts' => 'posts#category', as: category_posts`, now you can Just say: `category_posts_path('category_name')` and use `category_name` to query that attribute in posts controller's `category` method.

Comment: Try to keep your routes RESTful as they're less of a fuzz and easy for a your users to access. :)